# TextField inside a List in SwiftUI on macOS: Editing not working well

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield

This problem is with SwiftUI for a **macOS** app (not iOS or catalyst), using Xcode 12.4 (SwiftUI 2).
The problem is that editing of a TextField that is inside a List does not work well, in fact, it works so poorly that at first I thought I could not edit it at all.

This is the code, just as a simple example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name1 = "Hans"
    @State var name2 = "E"
    @State var name3 = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            TextField("Name 1", text: $name1)
            TextField("Name 2", text: $name2)
            TextField("Name 3", text: $name3)
        }
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
}
```

[image: TextField with focus]

And this is what I experience, trying to edit a field:

- For a non-empty field, single-tap **on the existing text**: it works (after a small, but annoying, 0.5 second delay).
- For a non-empty field, single-tap **outside** the existing text: nothing happens.
- For an empty field ("Name 3"), single-tap anywhere in the field: it works (after a small delay).
- **Double-tap** anywhere inside any field: nothing happens.

I hope this is not the intended behaviour. It is particularly problematic for a field that contains only a single character, making it difficult for the user (must tap exactly on the "E"). Am I doing something wrong here?

I noted the question [Editable TextField in SwiftUI List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57576128/668253), which is a bit similar, but that question reported the TextField to not work at all.

Comment: In your application, can you get away with not using `List` and just using a `ScrollView` instead?

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you for the suggestion! I can probably code around the problem in some way, as you suggest, but in this case I would really like to use what List has to offer.

Comment: I think this post is much helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70026160/115271

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name1 = "Hans"
    @State var name2 = "E"
    @State var name3 = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {}
          .overlay(VStack(spacing: 20){
              TextField("Name 1", text: $name1)
              TextField("Name 2", text: $name2)
              TextField("Name 3", text: $name3)
          })
          .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being late with my reply to this. This solution does not solve the problem because it eliminates the functionality that the List is supposed to provide. For example, reduce the height of the window, and you will see the vertical scrolling no longer works. The example illustrates the problem with only 3 entries, but in general there could be many entries, so scrolling is essential.