# SwiftUI Looping through Indices

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(numbers.indices) { index in
            let number = numbers[index]
            Text("\(number)")
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
Non-constant range: not an integer range
```

I can fix it using the following code:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
        
        let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1]
        
        var body: some View {
            
            List(numbers.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                let number = numbers[index]
                Text("\(number)")
            }
        }
    }
```

But I still don't understand what Non-constant range: not an integer range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The List View uses ForEach under the hood.

If you create your list with the 'data' only constructor the constructor for ForEach has the requirment for its data to be constant not dynamic:

```
extension ForEach where Data == Range<Int>, ID == Int, Content : View {

    /// Creates an instance that computes views on demand over a *constant*
    /// range.
    ///
    /// This instance only reads the initial value of `data` and so it does not
    /// need to identify views across updates.
    ///
    /// To compute views on demand over a dynamic range use
    /// `ForEach(_:id:content:)`.
    public init(_ data: Range<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content)
}
```

If you change your constructor to provide the id of each element yourself List uses the recommended ForEach(_:id:content:) constructor.

It needs the id specified in order to know when new elements have been added.

> /// To compute views on demand over a dynamic range use
> `ForEach(_:id:content:)`.

Update:

dynamic means you cann add or remove new items from your array.

For example:

```
List((0..<4)) { index in
    let number = numbers[index]
    Text("\(number)")
}
```

the range is constant. You cannot add or remove values and no warning will be shown.

/Update

Update 2:

Try this example:

```
@State var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1]

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        List(numbers.indices) { index in
            let number = numbers[index]
            Text("\(number)")
        }
        Button {
            numbers.append(9)
        } label: {
            Text("add")
        }

    }
    
}
```

If you click on the button the 9 will be added to your array but it will not show in your List.

Adding

```
id: \.self
```

and it starts working.

Comment: What does it mean constant and not dynamic? How is numbers array dynamic?

Comment: added clarification

Comment: added example usecase

Comment: But if the numbers array is declared as a let does it not make it constant. I mean you cannot add to an array if it is let.

Comment: But List does not know that.

Comment: Oh I understand. List has no idea that the list is constant.

Comment: If you use a mutable array in a `ForEach` you should never use `.indices` as the data. [Per the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1641719-indices): "If you mutate the collection while iterating over its indices, a strong reference can result in an unexpected copy of the collection." If you need the index in a `ForEach` See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026486/7129318)